# SQL Server 2005 - most straightforward way to grant read access to data AND code?

Tags: sql-server-2005

Is there a straightforward way to do this?  Basically, there's a large set of sql servers that some people need access to.  They only permissions they need is to read all data and all code.

Comment: The most straight forward way would be to create a single sql user that has these permissions on every server and let each user log in with it.  However, that would not be recommended.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind - looks like the answer is "view definition" permissions.